# Random Numbers with OpenCL using Random123

Tags: random, opencl

I have been looking at this lib [Random123](http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/releases/1.06/docs/index.html) and associated quote:

> One mysterious man came to my booth and asked what I knew about generating random numbers with OpenCL. I told him about implementations of the Mersenne Twister, but he wasn't impressed. He told me about a new technical paper that explains how to generate random numbers on GPUs by combining integer counters and block ciphers. In reverential tones, he said that counter-based random number generators (CBRNGs) produce numbers with greater statistical randomness than the MT and with much greater speed.

I was able to get a demo running using this kernel:

```
__kernel void counthits(unsigned n, __global uint2 *hitsp) {
    unsigned tid = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned hits = 0, tries = 0;
    threefry4x32_key_t k = {{tid, 0xdecafbad, 0xfacebead, 0x12345678}};
    threefry4x32_ctr_t c = {{0, 0xf00dcafe, 0xdeadbeef, 0xbeeff00d}};
    while (tries < n) {
        union {
            threefry4x32_ctr_t c;
            int4 i;
        } u;
        c.v[0]++;
        u.c = threefry4x32(c, k);
        long x1 = u.i.x, y1 = u.i.y;
        long x2 = u.i.z, y2 = u.i.w;
        if ((x1*x1 + y1*y1) < (1L<<62)) {
            hits++;
        }
        tries++;
        if ((x2*x2 + y2*y2) < (1L<<62)) {
            hits++;
        }
        tries++;
    }
    hitsp[tid].x = hits;
    hitsp[tid].y = tries;
}
```

My questions are now, will this not generate the same random numbers every time its run, a random number is based on the global id ? How can I generate new random numbers each time. Possible to provide a seed as a parameter for the kernel and then use that somehow?

Anyone who have been using this lib and can give me some more insight in the use of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The example code generates the same sequences of random numbers every time it is called.

To get different streams of random numbers, just initialize any of the values k[1..3] and/or c[1..3] differently.  You can initialize them from command line arguments, environment variables, time-of-day, saved state, /dev/urandom, or any other source.  Just be aware that:

a) if you initialize all of them exactly the same way in two different runs, then those two runs will get the same stream of random numbers

b) if you initialize them differently in two different runs, then those two runs will get different streams of random numbers.

Sometimes you want property a).  Sometimes you want property b).  Take a moment to think about which you want and be sure that you're doing what you intend.

More generally, the functions in the library, e.g., threefry4x32, have **no state**.  If you change any bit in the input (i.e., any bit in any of the elements of c or k), you'll get a completely different random, statistically independent, uniformly distributed output.

P.S.  I'm one of the authors of the library and the paper "Parallel Numbers:  As Easy as 1, 2, 3":
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2063405

If you're not a subscriber to the ACM digital library, the link above may hit a pay-wall.  Alternatively, you can obtain the paper free of charge by following the link on this page:

http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/index.html

Comment: Hi, I know it's an edge case but for case (b) don't you also have to make sure you don't accidently wrap around with the counter? e.g. if you seed one stream with {0,0,0,0} and another with {0,1,0,0} say then the first will eventually (after 2^64 incs) start producing the same as the second?

Comment: Wrapping a counter will start to reproduce a sequence that you may have seen earlier, which would be bad, but it's not a practical problem.  If you seed (i.e., set the key to) {0,0,0,0} in one sequence, then after 2^128 (not 2^64) iterations,the counter will wrap and you'll start to repeat the same sequence.  You won't roll over to the next key/seed value.  But iterating 2^128 times will take a very, VERY long time.  Far longer than you're willing to wait, I'd wager.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you with the library per se, but I can tell you that the most common way to generate random numbers in OpenCL is to save some state between calls to the kernel.

Random number generators usually use a state, from which a new state and a random number are generated.  In practice, this isn't complicated at all: you just pass an extra array that holds state.  In my codes, I implement random numbers as follows:

```
uint rand_uint(uint2* rvec) {  //Adapted from http://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/dt10/research/rngs-gpu-mwc64x.html
    #define A 4294883355U
    uint x=rvec->x, c=rvec->y; //Unpack the state
    uint res = x ^ c;          //Calculate the result
    uint hi = mul_hi(x,A);     //Step the RNG
    x = x*A + c;
    c = hi + (x<c);
    *rvec = (uint2)(x,c);      //Pack the state back up
    return res;                //Return the next result
    #undef A
}
inline float rand_float(uint2* rvec) {
    return (float)(rand_uint(rvec)) / (float)(0xFFFFFFFF);
}
__kernel void my_kernel(/*more arguments*/ __global uint2* randoms) {
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    uint2 rvec = randoms[index];

    //Call rand_uint or rand_float a number of times with "rvec" as argument.
    //These calls update "rvec" with new state, and return a random number

    randoms[index] = rvec;
}
```

. . . then, all you do is pass an extra array that holds the RNG's state into random.  In practice, you'll want to seed this array differently for each work item.

Comment: Reading the theory and comparing some of the code, it seems that the random123 is building on some of the same principles. I find the rot and bit shifting patterns at least. From what I am understanding, i think the random 123 is smart as no need for carrying the extra randoms array.  Two loop invariant's are used : 
threefry4x32_key_t k = {{tid, 0xdecafbad, 0xfacebead, 0x12345678}};
threefry4x32_ctr_t c = {{0, 0xf00dcafe, 0xdeadbeef, 0xbeeff00d}};

tid is the global id and 0 is the loop counter within a work item. Now at the end i am guessing that the 6 other numbers passed are seeds.

Comment: Hoping that someone can confirm this and if its just to pass in a struct with 6 numbers to use as the seed.

Comment: Well, either way, because all work items' kernels are the same across all invocations, if you don't pass in data to hold your random state, you'll get the same sequence of random numbers each time you call the kernel, in each work item.  That might be okay, but if you don't want that, you *must* pass in *some* kind of differing data for each work item each time.

Comment: Yes, only thing that i am confused about right now in the random123 lib is if the 6 numbers 0xdecafbad, 0xfacebead, 0x12345678 and 0xf00dcafe, 0xdeadbeef, 0xbeeff00d are just random numbers (the seed) or they are special numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`0xdecafbad`, `0xfacebead`, `0x12345678` and `0xf00dcafe`, `0xdeadbeef`, `0xbeeff00d` are just arbitrarily chosen numbers, they're not special.  Any other number (even 0) could be used in their place -- I'll add a comment to the example code.

You can replace any of them with variables that you pass in; the only requirement for avoiding undesirable repetition in the output random "stream" is that you avoid repeating the (c, k) input tuple.  The example code uses the thread id and loop index to ensure uniqueness, but you can easily add more variables to ensure uniqueness -- e.g. count the kernel invocations in the host code and pass that counter in, use that in place of one of the elements of k or c.

By the way, despite the name 'Counter-based random number generator', there's no requirement that the inputs (c, k) be 'counters', it's just that counters happen to be the most convenient idiom for ensuring that inputs don't repeat.

Comment: This may be helpful but it is hard to read! Can you try to break it up some?